# Combine Two Fields Into One

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, arcgis-10.5

I joined two tables to a shapefile and the output table has a field from each. Both fields represent the same thing so I'd like to combine them into one. You can see a clip of my fields below, where *most* of nulls are populated in the adjacent field.

[image]

Simply enough, I just want the final output to read as (based on the fields above)

```
<null>
Complete
Verified 
Verified
Verified
Verified
Construction
Construction
Construction
<null>
Verified
Approved
Complete
Verified
<null>
Complete
etc
```

I was thinking about using field calculator to say "If field 1 is None, field 1 = field 2" but that either doesn't work or I was getting the syntax wrong. Also, I have a few sets of three fields that I need to merge so that wouldn't work for that unless I calculated twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your field calculator, click the "show codeblock" button and enter this:

```
dim n
if isnull([columnone]) then
n = [columntwo]
else n = [columnone]
end if
```

and in the bottom field enter

```
n
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Should be easy enough to duplicate this a few times in my model for each field I need to merge!